# 'github.com/x/x' does not appear to be a git repository

Tags: git, repository

I don't know why but clearly https://github.com/spidio/node1 is a git repository.

I try cloning it...

```
git clone github.com/spidio/node1 pathname
```

Then error...

```
fatal: repository 'github.com/spidio/node1' does not exist
```

But it is, I don't understand.

You can check the link for yourself it does exist.

Anyone know what's happening?

Thanks a million!

Comment: Try `git clone https://github.com/spidio/node1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need start your link with https and end with .git

I just cloned your repository using this command:

`git clone https://github.com/spidio/node1.git pathname`

Comment: Thanks, I tried it with http, that's why it didn't work. :)

Comment: There is also a button on the top right that it says clone or download.

Comment: If you click that button you it shows the same link that I posted plus you could clone directly into your github desktop app or download the zip file itself.

Answer (score 1):

git clone **https://github.com/spidio/node1**

```
Cloning into 'node1'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
Checking connectivity... done.
```